# My WinForm custom control will not import into my WinForms app

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've been asked to wrap some existing code to make it work as a DLL/WinForms library. The code inherits from PictureBox and produces Excel-like grids, what MS refers to as "Extended Controls". To date, this has been used simply by adding the source files to the project.

To learn about the general concepts, I made a new .Net Framework Class Library project and added a single public class, CustomPictureBox, which inherits from PictureBox. I then overrode OnPaint and OnClick to draw lines between click locations. That produced a DLL. I made a new WinForms app (Framework 4.7.x), opened the default Form1, and dragged the DLL into the Toolbox. When I did so, CustomPictureBox appeared in the list. I dragged that into Form1, and presto, my paint view was working. (I was happily surprised how easy it was.)

I then made another .Net Framework Class Library project and included the source files that produce the Excel-like view. The main Workbook class is public, and also inherits from PictureBox. When I try to drag this DLL into the Toolbox it beeps at me. I then tried Choose Toolbox Items to add it manually, which gets:

```
There are no components in ...\OXL.dll that can be placed on the Toolbox.
```

I found [this thread on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199202/there-are-no-components-in-dll-that-can-be-placed-on-toolbox), and tried all of these solutions. The one that caught my eye was the one about lacking a parameterless construction, which it did, but adding one did not change anything. [Another suggested restarting VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621558/visual-studio-do-not-add-my-component-from-a-dll-to-the-toolbox-even-if-i-refe), but no luck there. A [thread found elsewhere](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/3274) suggests that it might require other references to also be included, but I am not sure how I might figure those out, there is nothing in the console or error messages that might be useful.

Can anyone offer any other things that I might not have implemented that might cause this? Or other reasons that this error might occur?

I'm happy to post the code for my little test control, but it worked fine so I'm not sure if its useful. Let me know!

Comment: "_I'm happy to post the code_" : Perhaps you could post a GitHub repo with the two class library projects and the Winforms App project all under the same solution **.sln** so we could really get a look at it? It might be prohibitive to try and reproduce this otherwise.

Comment: The Excel-like code I cannot post, and that's the one with the problem. I realize this is far from optimal! My *feeling*, and uninformed one at that, is that I am missing some public functions that the Toolbox looks for, but I cannot find a list anywhere on MS's site and my Googling goes nowhere.

Comment: ...and now it is not a feeling but a fact. Changing a number of properties and handlers to Public made it appear in the Toolbox and work in my form (and it even draws the preview, which it didn't do in the original version!).